# What is the best way to convert a winning chance into a Bool?

Tags: swift

In my game I need to make an attack. This is based on chance.

- If the attack succeeds: `return true`
- If the attack fails: `return false`

Here is my function I am trying to complete:

```
func didWinAttack(withChances chance: Double) -> Bool {

}
```

For example, `didWinAttack(withChances: 0.7)` means that I should win ~70% of the time. This means that the *majority* of the time I should get `true` as a result.

What is the best way to achieve this? Can `Type.random(Range)` come in useful here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you suggested, you can just generate a random Double and compare the two.

```
func didWinAttack(withChances chance: Double) -> Bool {
    return chance > Double.random(in: 0..<1)
}
```